# Is it possible to implement read through and write through in apache ignite using jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, ignite

I wanted to read and write data from underlying db with Apache ignite . I'm doing a spring boot app so i just want to know  whether  i can use JPA features for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, Apache Ignite does not implement any JPA APIs. So you can't access data stored in Ignite in JPA fashion.

However, you can probably use JPA to cache data in Ignite while writing it to, and reading from, underlying JPA store. In this case you will need to implement your own [`CacheStore`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/CacheStore.html). Example: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain-advanced-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/store (this is based on Mongo but you can rewrite it to use JPA).